# Can I use map to perform iterative update on a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's part of the code I am working on. My goal is to start from the empty list `D_E`, then accumulate results of `de` into `D_E`, from the `for` loops.

```
D_E = []
for num_flip in range (0, N):
    probsu = []
    de = []
    for i in range (L):
        probsui = []
        for j in range (nuni):
            counts = results.get_counts((nuni*i)+j)
            prob = absorb_counts(counts)[num_flip]/sum(counts.values())
            probsui.append(prob)
            pz_bar = np.average(probsui)
        probsu.append(pz_bar)
        de.append(np.abs(5 - math.comb(N, num_flip)))
    spec = dict(zip(EW,probsu))
    # Here, I want to perform an iterative update of D_E
    D_E = list(map(add, D_E, de))

D_E = dict(zip(EW, [0.5*i for i in D_E]))
print(D_E)
```

I initialized `D_E` to be an empty list, and in my `for` loop for `num_flip`, I am trying to update `D_E` by adding `de`, another list. I am not appending `de`, but want to add all its elements to `D_E`. Since I am repeating this procedure, I wonder if I could use `map` in the for loop, and update `D_E`. However, currently my final result of `D_E` is just `{}`. I don't know where I am doing wrong.

I tried a simpler example: `D_E = dict(zip([1,2,3], [0.5*i for i in [1,2,3]]))` and that worked well, I wonder how can I use `map` in the for loop in my case?

Comment: It's not clear what you want `D_E` to be. It sounds like you want `D_E.extend(de)`. The code you have now is equivalent to `D_E = [add(x,y) for zip(D_E, de)]`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the comment! I want `D_E` to be a dictionary, the keys are `EW`, and values are results obtained from the `for` loop for `num_flip `.

Comment: But what is `D_E` supposed to be a list of? It's not clear if `list(map(add, D_E, de))` is doing what you want, or if it's just the attempt you are making.

Comment: @chepner I want to start the code by preparing a list of values of `D_E` through `for` loops, then combining the keys to become a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide, at the very least, an example value for `de` and what `D_E` should look like before and after they are "combined".

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I will consider posting a new question after updating my code

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly: `de` is a list of numbers (I doesn't matter what, now). At one point, you do `D_E = list(map(add, D_E, de))`, which means that you expect `D_E`  to have the same length of `de`, and you are essentially summing the two lists element-wise (I'm assuming your `add` is `operator.add`). If that is the case, `D_E` will always be empty, because `map` will only run through the length of your shortest list (which is empty, in this case). Is that correct? I still couldn't understand what is your goal though.

Comment: @nonDucor That's exactly right, thanks so much for the comment! My goal is to start from the empty list, then accumulate results of `de` from the `for` loops.

Comment: `L` is undefined in your code.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "accumulate" results. Your `map` is summing them, but since `D_E` is empty, it never gets updated. Do you want to extend `D_E` with the values in `de`?

Comment: @nonDucor I want to first extend `D_E` with `de`, then update/accumulate `D_E` with new results of `de`.

Comment: Ok, so in the first run of your loop (when `num_flip == 0`), you want to set `D_E = de`. On the subsequent runs, you want to do the sum `D_E = map(add, D_E, de)`, right? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: If you just want to accumulate values from `de` in `D_E`, that's `D_E.extend(de)`. No need for `map` at all.

Comment: @nonDucor That's right, thanks so much!

Comment: @ZR-, if my proposed solution works, please accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion on the comments, you need to initialise `D_E` before summing the new values. The following code should work (I left the rest of the code as is, even the parts that are never used, such as `spec`).

```py
D_E = [0 for _ in range(L)]
for num_flip in range (0, N): # Note: range normally starts from 0, so range(N) is enough
    probsu = []
    de = []
    for i in range (L):
        probsui = []
        for j in range (nuni):
            counts = results.get_counts((nuni*i)+j)
            prob = absorb_counts(counts)[num_flip]/sum(counts.values())
            probsui.append(prob)
            pz_bar = np.average(probsui)
        probsu.append(pz_bar)   # Note: this is never used
        de.append(np.abs(5 - math.comb(N, num_flip)))
    spec = dict(zip(EW,probsu))   # Note: this is never used
    # Here, I want to perform an iterative update of D_E
    D_E = list(map(add, D_E, de))

D_E = dict(zip(EW, [0.5*i for i in D_E]))
print(D_E)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much for the help!!